# Servlets:java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Welcome

Tags: java, servlets

I am trying to make a simple Servlet Code.Initially it used to work fine but now posing a problem. kindly help
index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="welcome">
<input type="submit" value="go"/></form>

</body>
</html>


web.xml:


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>9-01-2014</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
  <servlet-name>Welcome</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>Welcome</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>

  <servlet-name>Welcome</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/welcome</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Welcom.java:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class Welcome
 */
@WebServlet("/Welcome")
public class Welcome extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public Welcome() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.println("Welcome");
    }



}
```

Error Report:

```
Jan 09, 2014 2:41:27 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:/Program Files/Java/jre7/bin/server;C:/Program Files/Java/jre7/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jre7/lib/amd64;C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Utilities 1.3.4\;C:\strawberry\c\bin;C:\strawberry\perl\site\bin;C:\strawberry\perl\bin;D:\eclipse-jee-indigo-SR2-win32-x86_64\eclipse;;.
Jan 09, 2014 2:41:28 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:9-01-2014' did not find a matching property.
Jan 09, 2014 2:41:28 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Jan 09, 2014 2:41:28 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Jan 09, 2014 2:41:28 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 2179 ms
Jan 09, 2014 2:41:29 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Jan 09, 2014 2:41:29 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.42
Jan 09, 2014 2:41:30 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Jan 09, 2014 2:41:30 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Jan 09, 2014 2:41:30 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 1191 ms
Jan 09, 2014 2:41:34 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Marking servlet Welcome as unavailable
Jan 09, 2014 2:41:34 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Allocate exception for servlet Welcome
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Welcome
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1714)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:527)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:509)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1144)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:865)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:136)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I  have added servlet-api jar file .
But still couldnot work it.

Comment: Is your welcome classs in defualt package.

Comment: yes, i have not used any package.

Comment: @user3176775 Are you running this from eclipse or deploying a war file manually?

Comment: It seems you are using servlet3.0 annotations and web.xml. Can you try removing the servlet mapping from web.xml

Comment: i tried with the package too and i am running this from eclipse

Comment: Juned , i didnt get you .Kindly can you please elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

It is better to put this class into some package and then give in `Servlet-class` such as `com.somePackage.Welcome`

Comment: Its better, but is that why the OP is encountering issues?

Comment: @KevinBowersox, I faced this kind of issue while I was learning servlets. Maybe I don't remember perfectly but this could be the issue.

Comment: @Prasad without package servlet also works perfectly.